# How do I switch off debugging in Aptana?

Tags: php, aptana, xdebug

I've been trying to understand how to use Debugging in Aptana Studio 3 for a PHP web application. After much frustration I've decided I'll leave it for now.

Only problem is that my IDE is now always jumping into debug mode. If Aptana is open, then any attempt to run my app results in Aptana launching a debug sort of interruption.

I've deleted the Debug Configurations, shut down, restarted, to no avail.

Specifically, Apatana is saying to me

```
XDebug JIT Session [Remote Launch]
  PHP Application (port 9000)
      Remote Launch (stepping)
         php/index.php.{main} : lineno 21
```

Where is the off switch :(

Comment: In the absence of any better knowledge - reinstall

Comment: Have you looked at the settings in `Window > Preferences > Run/Debug > Launching`? There are some rules there about when to launch debug mode.

Comment: Thank you... that's what I was looking for. I'll try replicate the problem later (I have a clean install right now haha). This whole debugging thing is quite frustrating to master.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to switch from **debug** perspective to default **web** perspective,

navigate to ***Window > Open Perspective > Other...***.

In the dialog box select **Web(default)** and click **OK**.

You'll be back to your regular layout or perspective.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I view the cookies for the site that keeps sending debug requests, there is a cookie named `XDEBUG_SESSION`. Deleting this cookie and ensuring the `XDEBUG_SESSION_START=ECLIPSE_DBGP_1412660958` is not in the URL makes the site stop requesting debug.